# Reverse a AVX register containing doubles using a single AVX intrinsic

Tags: c, sse, vectorization, simd, avx

If I have an AVX register with 4 doubles in them and I want to store the reverse of this in another register, is it possible to do this with a single intrinsic command?

For example: If I had 4 floats in a SSE register, I could use:

```
_mm_shuffle_ps(A,A,_MM_SHUFFLE(0,1,2,3));
```

Can I do this using, maybe `_mm256_permute2f128_pd()`? I don't think you can address each individual double using the above intrinsic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You actually need 2 permutes to do this:

- `_mm256_permute2f128_pd()` only permutes in 128-bit chunks.
- `_mm256_permute_pd()` does not permute across 128-bit boundaries.

So you need to use both:

```
inline __m256d reverse(__m256d x){
    x = _mm256_permute2f128_pd(x,x,1);
    x = _mm256_permute_pd(x,5);
    return x;
}
```

Test:

```
int main(){
    __m256d x = _mm256_set_pd(13,12,11,10);

    cout << x.m256d_f64[0] << "  " << x.m256d_f64[1] << "  " << x.m256d_f64[2] << "  " << x.m256d_f64[3] << endl;
    x = reverse(x);
    cout << x.m256d_f64[0] << "  " << x.m256d_f64[1] << "  " << x.m256d_f64[2] << "  " << x.m256d_f64[3] << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
10  11  12  13
13  12  11  10
```

Comment: Yep.  Worth keeping in mind that AVX2 will add a full permute, even if you can't use it today, `VPERMPD` / `_mm256_permute4x64_pd`.  Intel's reference documents have more details.

Comment: Any idea how the latency of the two instructions compare with each other?

Comment: I mean the latency of "_mm_shuffle_ps()" to reverse a SSE register and the above reverse operation on an AVX register

Comment: @user1715122 I have no idea. You can probably add it up from [Agner Fog's tables](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf) . Of course actual performance will be more complicated due to other factors.

Answer (score 4):

Support for lane-crossing shuffles with granularity finer 128-bit was new **with AVX2**:

```
_mm256_permute4x64_pd(vec, _MM_SHUFFLE(0,1,2,3));  // i.e. 0b00011011
```

[`VPERMPD ymm1, ymm2/m256, imm8`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpermpd) runs with the same throughput and latency as other lane-crossing shuffles (like `VPERM2F128`) on Intel CPUs.  Also [in the intrinsics finder](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#techs=MMX,SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2,Other&text=vpermp&ig_expand=4405,5863).

On AMD Zen1 (and [Excavator](http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/AuthenticAMD0660F01_K15_Carrizo_InstLatX64.txt)), `vpermpd` is faster than 2-input `vperm2f128`.  Their vector ALUs internally are only 128-bits wide; 256-bit vector instructions are decoded into at least 2 uops, but it takes more for lane-crossing operations, especially one that can read any of 4 total lanes. (Unfortunately the decoders don't just look at the immediate bits when picking uops for vperm2f128).  Manual `vextractf128` / `vinsertf128` would be better than `vperm2f128` on Bulldozer-family and Zen1, but that would be quite bad everywhere else. https://uops.info/.  I think `vpermpd` is optimal on Excavator / Zen1, 3 uops vs. at least 4 to in-lane reverse and then swap halves with `vextracti128` / `vinsert128`.

---

There are a few CPUs with FMA3 but not AVX2, e.g. AMD Piledriver and Steamroller.  On Intel, AVX2 and FMA were both new with Haswell.  AMD Bulldozer-family is obsolete but still around in home computers, so even if your function takes advantage of AVX1 + FMA, your options are to also require AVX2 and have those few CPUs fall back to something even worse, (e.g. AVX1 without FMA), or to make yet another version of your function.