# How to set all elements in a __m256d to, say, the 3rd element of another __m256d?

Tags: sse, avx

With 4 packed `float` (`__m128`), I can use the SSE intrinsic

```
__m128 X;
__m128 H = _mm_shuffle_ps(X,X,_MM_SHUFFLE(3,3,3,3));
```

to set all elements of `H` to the third element of `X` (is this the fastest way?)

Now, I want to do the same with 4 packed `double` (`__m256d`). I naively coded

```
__m256d X;
__m256d H = _mm256_shuffle_pd(X,X,_MM_SHUFFLE(3,3,3,3));
```

but this doesn't do the right thing! Instead it sets H={X[1],X[1],X[3],X[3]}.

So, how to do it right?

**EDIT**

using Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 0 @ 2.60GHz

Comment: See this question: [Reverse a AVX register containing doubles using a single AVX intrinsic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422747/reverse-a-avx-register-containing-doubles-using-a-single-avx-intrinsic)

Comment: There is no equivalent for the 256-bit vectors. You need to use two shuffle/permute instrinsics because one only permutes in 128-bit chunks and the other cannot permute across 128-bit boundaries.

Comment: @Mysticial good. So can you provide the code needed (as answer)? Otherwise, I'll figure it out myself (and answer my own question).

Comment: Maybe later. I have class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, after Mystical's comments, I could work it out myself:

```
template<int K>
inline __mm256d pick_single(__m256d x)
{
   __m256 t = _mm256_permute2f128_pd(x,x, K&2?49:32);
   return _mm256_permute_pd(t,K&1?15:0);
}
```

yields the desired result. Thanks for your help, Mystical!

Answer (score 2):

It is not always optimal, but asking your compiler what it thinks can be a nice hint.

```
#include <x86intrin.h>
__m256d f(__m256d x){
  __m256i m={3,3,3,3};
  return __builtin_shuffle(x,m);
}
```

With gcc-4.8, this generates:

```
vpermilpd   $15, %ymm0, %ymm0
vperm2f128  $17, %ymm0, %ymm0, %ymm0
```

clang has a different builtin for shuffling, I don't know if other compilers have something.