# Permute content of AVX register

Tags: c++, c, intrinsics, avx, avx2

I have an AVX register with four double precision values. Now I need to perform some arithmetics individually on each element. A semplification of what I need to do is the following.

```
Situation:
  a = [a4 a3 a2 a1]
  w = [ 0  0  0 w1]
  x = [ 0  0  0 x1]
  y = [ 0  0  0 y1]
  z = [ 0  0  0 z1]

Desired result:
  w = [-- -- -- w1+a1]
  x = [-- -- -- x1+a2]
  y = [-- -- -- y1+a3]
  z = [-- -- -- z1+a4]
```

Except the desired result is not just the sum of two values but a more complicated arithmetic expression of them. Where I put `--`, I mean that I don't care about those values, which will be discarded.

I figured out I could permute the register `a` using a permutation operation (see e.g. [Reverse a AVX register containing doubles using a single AVX intrinsic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422747/reverse-a-avx-register-containing-doubles-using-a-single-avx-intrinsic)). My only problem is that those intrinsics require an immediate, i.e. a compile-time value, while I need to perform this operation dynamically.

I found permutation intrinsics which operate on integers contained in other registers, like [_mm256_permutevar_pd](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=3891&techs=AVX,AVX2&text=permutevar), but none of them permute across lanes (e.g. it would be impossible using these instructions to have `a3` in the first place. The only way to do what I want with these instructions would be to use an `if`, which I would rather avoid.

Should I have a permutation across 128-bit lanes subject to an `if` condition followed by a dynamic permutation within lanes? Or are there better solutions? I'm interested in both performance and maintainability. I can use up to AVX2 instructions. Assembly is an option but I would prefer instrinsics.

Comment: Store in memory as a vector, read back as a scalar?

Comment: I just had a huge speedup in my application when I moved away from such a solution. I already implemented the "store in memory" solution. Now I would like to see the difference when the whole operation is done in registers.

Comment: So you need your results as 4 separate scalar doubles?  (that's the same thing as having it in the low element of a vector with the other elements don't-care).  Where does the non-compile-time-constant shuffle come in?  I don't see why you can't just unpack with `vextractf128` and then get the high half of each `__m128d` into a scalar `double` with `vmovhlps` or something.  You know which vector element goes with which variable name...

Comment: Correct, I need to treat these values as separate scalars. The instruction `vextractf128` (which is used in the intrinsics like `_mm256_extractf128_pd`) requires the index to be a static value. I need the index to be dynamic. I can't know at compile-time in which order the values are taken. [Another use case is when I'm looping over these values with a `for` loop. Since I'm supporting both `float` and `double` as base type, I can't just manually unroll the loop `for (int i = 0; i < packSize; ++i)`, since it would need different iterations for different types.]

Comment: For the single precision I'm using the `_mm256_permutevar8x32_ps` intrinsic, while for the double precision I can use the same with two casts and a customized index. That is working now, but  I wonder if this solution is the best one.

Comment: I'm sort of missing the problem - don't you always need the same 3 permutations? Namely to get the 2nd, 3rd and 4th value down to the 1st position?

Comment: Can you post code that does a simplified version of what you're doing, but still requires variable extract / shuffle indices?  None of what you said makes it clear why you think you can't use code that just unpacks a vector to four scalar doubles, or eight scalar floats.  Is this just because of how you want to compile the same loop twice, for float and double?  Sounds like you should refactor something instead of writing code that probably compiles to sub-optimal instructions for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you could do whatever the `+` is representing using SIMD operations after packing `[ z y x w ]` into a vector.  But if not:

Extract all 4 elements to scalar `double`s the normal way, and then do whatever you want:

```
void unpack_256_to_scalar(__m256d a) {
    // unpack to two 128b halves
    __m128d a01 = _mm256_castpd256_pd128(a);  // extractf128_pd(a, 0) should also compile the same way, if you like more-consistent C instead of code that matches the asm you expect
    __m128d a23 = _mm256_extractf128_pd(a, 1);

    // and then halves of each 128b vector
    double a0 = _mm_cvtsd_f64(a01);
    double a1 = _mm_cvtsd_f64(_mm_unpackhi_pd(a01,a01));
    double a2 = _mm_cvtsd_f64(a23);
    double a3 = _mm_cvtsd_f64(_mm_unpackhi_pd(a23,a23));
    ...
    // use the results
}
```

This [compiles (on the Godbolt compiler explorer)](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g6,options:'-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B11+-Wall+-Wextra+-O3+-fno-verbose-asm+-march%3Dhaswell',source:'%23include+%3Cimmintrin.h%3E%0A%0Adouble+w,x,y,z%3B%0A%0Adouble+unpack_256_to_scalar(__m256d+a)+%7B%0A++++//+unpack+to+two+128b+halves%0A++++__m128d+a01+%3D+_mm256_castpd256_pd128(a)%3B++//+extractf128_pd(a,+0)+should+also+compile+the+same+way,+if+you+like+more-consistent+C+instead+of+code+that+matches+the+asm+you+expect%0A++++__m128d+a23+%3D+_mm256_extractf128_pd(a,+1)%3B%0A%0A++++//+and+then+halves+of+each+128b+vector%0A++++double+a0+%3D+_mm_cvtsd_f64(a01)%3B%0A++++double+a1+%3D+_mm_cvtsd_f64(_mm_unpackhi_pd(a01,a01))%3B%0A++++double+a2+%3D+_mm_cvtsd_f64(a23)%3B%0A++++double+a3+%3D+_mm_cvtsd_f64(_mm_unpackhi_pd(a23,a23))%3B%0A%0A++++//+Use+the+results+so+the+code+isn!'t+optimized+away.%0A++++asm+volatile(%22%23+just+a+comment%22+::+%22x%22(a0),+%22x%22(a1),+%22x%22(a2),+%22x%22(a3))%3B%0A++++return+a0%3B%0A%0A+++//return+a0*a1*a2*a3%3B%0A%0A++/*%0A++++w%2B%3Da0%3B%0A++++x+%2B%3D+a1%3B%0A++++y+%2B%3D+a2%3B%0A++++z+%2B%3D+a3%3B%0A++++return+z%3B%0A++*/%0A%7D')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3) to only three instructions with clang, or 4 with gcc because it's being dumb with register allocation:

```
unpack_256_to_scalar(double __vector(4)):
    vextractf128    xmm1, ymm0, 0x1
    vunpckhpd       xmm2, xmm0, xmm0
    vmovapd xmm3, xmm1                 # gcc should have use vunpckhpd xmm3, xmm1,xmm1.  This wasted mov is a missed-optimization bug.
    vunpckhpd       xmm1, xmm1, xmm1
    # the empty asm statement emitted the empty string here.
    vzeroupper
    ret
```

Each of the three instructions produces a different element as the low element of its vector result.  No constants are needed, not even immediate constants (which is why I chose `unpackhi_pd` instead of `shufpd` or [`vpermilpd`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/VPERMILPD.html) which clang uses when it's generating shuffles from its internal representation of the data movement.)

Using a variable-shuffle that needs a vector as a control-mask would be insane here.  Nothing about this appears to require any dynamic / variable-shuffle or extract.

BTW, see the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for some links on writing high-performance code.